# Django RF, Error in Date comparison in serializer validation field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented below serializer validation to check if user entered date (yyyy-mm-dd) is within this week or at least by today.

But I'm getting an error `KeyError at 'today'`

```
class TableCreateUpdateserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tablerequireDate = serializers.DateField()
    today = datetime.datetime.today()

    class Meta:
        model = Tables
        fields = ['tablerequireDate', 'tablerequiretime']
                  

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['tablerequireDate'] >= data['today']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Date must be today or within 7 days")
        return data
```

Comment: try ```self.today``` see if that works?

Comment: got error TypeError at /api/create/
can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **key error:**
Your data does not contain today filed. Your class does. so use `self.today`

for **type error:**
Your today field is of type `datetime.datetime` and you are passing `datetime.date` in your data. Both should be same. use `datetime.date.today()`

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to add it to the class, when you can declare it inside the `validate` method:

```
def validate(self, data):
    if data['tablerequireDate'] >= datetime.today():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            "Date must be today or within 7 days")
    return data
```